# Need to calculate partial sum: $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{(n+2)}}{(2n^2+1)^{n/2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need to calculate the partial sum of this series:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{n+2}}{(2n^2+1)^{n/2}}$$

I tried to telescope, but the equation is too difficult for me, and I tried d'Alembert method to calculate partial sum, but it didn't work for me.

Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: I see no reason to think this has a closed form.

Comment: How do i determine if this series converges or diverges?

Comment: This series is convergent by comparison test. Indeed $$\frac{n^{n+2}}{\sqrt{(2n^2+1)^n}} < \frac{n^{n+2}}{\sqrt{(2n^2)^n}} = \frac{n^2}{(\sqrt2)^n} $$

Comment: It is easy to use the root test to see it iconverges.

Comment: Have you tried any numerical approach ?

Comment: Show some of your working. We can do interesting things for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You are facing the general problem of $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n \qquad \text{where} \qquad  a_n=\frac{n^{n+2}}{(2n^2+1)^{n/2}}$$

If there was not the $1$ in denominator, the problem will be  much simpler. On the other hand $1 \ll 2n^2$ very quickly.

So, why not to use the binomial expansion and write
$$a_n=\frac{n^{n+2}}{(2n^2+1)^{n/2}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{n}{2}}{k}\,2^{-k-\frac{n}{2}}\, n^{2-2 k} $$ and then switch the summation order ?

This should make the problem quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we do not have a close-form for the partial sum of the
original series. However, if you just want to determine whether the
series is convergent or not, you may proceed as follows:

Observe that

\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \frac{n^{(n+2)}}{(2n^{2}+1)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\\
 & \leq & \frac{n^{(n+2)}}{(2n^{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}}\\
 & = & \frac{n^{2}}{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}}$
is convergent by ratio test. For,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{2}}{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n^{2}}{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}}}\\
 & = & \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
 & < & 1.
\end{eqnarray*}
Then, by comparison test, the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{(n+2)}}{(2n^{2}+1)^{\frac{n}{2}}}$
also converges.